# Cython and Scipy

Tags: scipy, cython

I'm cythonizing a skript that containes scipy.stats.norm() function for calculation of implied vola. 
Instead of scipy.stats.norm() I use scipy.special.ndtr() since this is somewhat faster. However, when profiling my script most time (50 from 125sec) is still spent within this function, in particular within _distn_infrastructure.py:1610(cdf). 
That's the function:

```
def cdf(self, x, *args, **kwds):
        """
        in class rv_continuous(rv_generic):
        Cumulative distribution function of the given RV.

        Parameters
        ----------
        x : array_like
            quantiles
        arg1, arg2, arg3,... : array_like
            The shape parameter(s) for the distribution (see docstring of the
            instance object for more information)
        loc : array_like, optional
            location parameter (default=0)
        scale : array_like, optional
            scale parameter (default=1)

        Returns
        -------
        cdf : ndarray
            Cumulative distribution function evaluated at `x`

        """
        args, loc, scale = self._parse_args(*args, **kwds)
        x, loc, scale = map(asarray, (x, loc, scale))
        args = tuple(map(asarray, args))
        x = (x-loc)*1.0/scale
        cond0 = self._argcheck(*args) & (scale > 0)
        cond1 = (scale > 0) & (x > self.a) & (x < self.b)
        cond2 = (x >= self.b) & cond0
        cond = cond0 & cond1
        output = zeros(shape(cond), 'd')
        place(output, (1-cond0)+np.isnan(x), self.badvalue)
        place(output, cond2, 1.0)
        if any(cond):  # call only if at least 1 entry
            goodargs = argsreduce(cond, *((x,)+args))
            place(output, cond, self._cdf(*goodargs))
        if output.ndim == 0:
            return output[()]
        return output
```

However, I neighter see any function that does the actual cdf calculation nor a call of a another function that actually does it. I tried to print the output of this function via   inserting

```
print output
```

before

```
return output
```

however, the print command is highlighted as wrong syntax and when running the skript there is no print of the output. How to go from here? I somehow need to speed up the norm-CDF calculation.

Comment: You say you use `scipy.special.ndtr` instead of `scipy.stats.norm`, so why is your code spending *any* time in that `cdf` method?  That's part of `scipy.stats`.

Comment: Indeed. There was another code snipped that still called scipiy.stats. After changing this as well I got a 10 times speed increase.

Comment: Are you running Python 3?  That requires `print(...)`

Comment: No, it's Python 2.7.8. The print() command only gives error when applied within scipy files.

Comment: Ah, I found the reason: On top of the scipy script there is "from __future__ import print". That's why here the Python 2.7 print command doesn't work.

Comment: The print problem is most likely because you mix tabs and spaces in the same file.